# Is asparagus deer resistant?

Tags: vegetables, pests, asparagus, wildlife, deer

I love the idea of edible landscapes, and asparagus is a nice early season treat that can wind up looking great in certain areas. BUT I don't want to waste time planting it all over if the deer are just going to eat it.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Mine is inside the fence right now, so I don't know and would be interested to hear other's experiences. We had it outside the fence when I grew up (actually the only thing we had "fenced" were the blueberries in bird netting), but where/when I grew up deer were quite actively hunted and not prone to the bold behaviors of suburban deer that nobody shoots at. Hmm - I guess I can say that there's some "wild" asparagus (feral, more likely) outside the fence that does not seem to get killed off.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - this is a common issue for us on Long Island. Deer are eating all kinds of plants that were once considered deer resistant. Probably for the same reasons you describe - that and their increasing populations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, asparagus is listed as deer resistant <sup>[1,](http://njaes.rutgers.edu/deerresistance/)[2,](http://www.wirelessdeerfence.com/lp/deer-resistant-vegetables/)[3,](http://www.almanac.com/content/deer-resistant-plants) etc</sup>, but in my experience, they love the new shoots, and can be almost as bad in this respect as groundhogs, at least in my yard. They do seem to avoid adult plants when possible. So, if you can't fence, it may get eaten as it emerges, as it sounds like your local deer are widening their menus.